# Ubuntu Server 18.0.4 Can't login

Tags: 18.04

I have set up and installed ubuntu server 18.
How ever the user name and pass I set at setup will not work.
Have I done something wrong or some kind of bug?

Comment: Just check the keyboard layout is the same that the one you used in the installer...

Comment: Yup sure is typed a for username and password after reinstall still no luck.